# How to change chart type on click of dropdown in Angular 15 typescript using Highcharts?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to change the chart type on click of dropdown but I am clueless that how to do the same in Angular component typescript file.

I am trying something like this but it isn't  working?

```
onOptionsSelected(value:string){
    console.log("the selected value is " + value);
    if(value="line"){
     
       this.showChart1();
    }
    else if(value=="bar"){
        this.chartData.destroy();
        this.showChart2();
    }
    else if(value=="area"){
    
      this.showChart3();
    }
    else if(value=="column"){
     
      this.showChart4();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the official wrapper repository you have a demo showing how to update the chart in an optimal way. If you have `updateFlag` set correctly, it comes down to updating `chartOptions`:

```js
handleUpdate() {
  this.chartOptions.series[0] = {
    type: this.chartOptions.series[0].type === 'column' ? 'line' : 'column',
  };

  this.updateFlag = true;
}
```

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-update-optimal-way-pjgqgg

Docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details